# Generate a heteroscedastic data set

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, data

I want to generate a variable that we can call $y$ that is a linear function of a normally-distributed variable, $x$, and a normal random term, $\epsilon$, which variance's change in function of $x$. Until now, this is what I came up with.

```
SeedRandom["Hétéroscédasticité"];
Clear[x]; x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5000, 100], 100];

Clear[ϵ]; ϵ = Flatten@Table[
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2*Sort[x][[i]]], 1], {i, 1, 100}]

Clear[y, z]; y = 4360 + 10*Sort[x] + ϵ;
```

Does anyone know a better way of formulating it?

Comment: Why are you sorting the x every step of the way?

Comment: `y =4360+10 x+ Sqrt[ 2 x] RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],100]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must want the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ to be normally distributed with a variance that is a function of $x$.  (For this the distribution of $x$ is irrelevant as we are conditioning on $x$ and you probably want $x$ to be non-negative.)

```
(* Sample size *)
n = 1000

(* Generate some values for x (doesn't have to be a random sample) *)
x = Range[1, n]/100;

(* Generate y conditional on x *)
y = a + b x + x RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ], n] /.
    {a -> 1, b -> 1, σ -> 1};

(* Display data *)
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]
```

[image: Random sample conditional on x]

Comment: Ok this is working fine. But why do you do a "replace all" after you specify the form of y? Why not directly put the numbers in?

Comment: Whether good programming style or not, it's just a style that I tend to use for a group of parameters.  Sometimes I'll use something like `parms = {a -> 1, b -> 1}` and then use `/.parms`.  (And it's a "replace" rather than "replace all".)

Comment: Anyway, I find it quite neat a formulation, helps comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not really need to `Sort` the x, drop the first five characters:

`x = Sort@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5000, 100], 100]`

`y = Table[Random[NormalDistribution[0, 2 x[[j]]]], {j, Length@x}]`

Comment: No I don't need to sort the x. And I don't remember what I was thinking when I did. Got confused...